# translating pandas group to sql(ite): limit in group

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlite

### The Problem

I'm trying to translate a pandas query into a SQL(ite) query. The main issue in my translation to SQL is trying to place a limit in a group.

Here is a setup (in python) of an example database.

```py
import sqlite3
from random import choices

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    dict(
        montecarlo=choices(range(1, 501), k=10_000),
        time=choices(range(1, 1_000), k=10_000),
        tracking_id=choices([1, 2, 3], k=10_000),
        passed=choices([True, False], k=10_000),
    )
)

df.sort_values(by=["montecarlo", "time"], inplace=True)

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
df.to_sql("mytable", conn, index=False, if_exists="replace")
```

So the query I would write in pandas is this

```py
import numpy as np

def first_time_if_exists(df: pd.DataFrame) -> float:
    try:
        return df.loc[df.passed.eq(1)].time.iloc[0]
    except IndexError:
        # Sometimes there is no pass for a given df
        return np.NaN


result = (
    df.groupby(["montecarlo", "tracking_id"])  # Group by montecarlo and id
    .apply(first_time_if_exists)  # Get time of first pass for each group
    .rename("first_time")  # Give the pandas series a name
    .reset_index()  # Pop montecarlo and tracking_id back into normal columns
)
```

where `result` looks like this

```py
      montecarlo  tracking_id  first_time
0              1            1        51.0
1              1            2       289.0
2              1            3        14.0
3              2            1       201.0
4              2            2       121.0
...          ...          ...         ...
1492         499            2       143.0
1493         499            3       129.0
1494         500            1        25.0
1495         500            2       147.0
1496         500            3       251.0

[1497 rows x 3 columns]
```

### What I've tried so far

I think I've been able to get most of the way there with my SQL query.

```sql
SELECT 
    montecarlo, tracking_id, time
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    passed = 1
GROUP BY 
    montecarlo, tracking_id;
```

However, this gives me all the times for each group instead of just the first. I've also tried

```sql
SELECT 
    montecarlo, tracking_id, time
FROM 
    mytable
WHERE 
    passed = 1
LIMIT
    1
GROUP BY 
    montecarlo, tracking_id;
```

but the place I've put my `LIMIT` is illegal syntax.

Comment: Good effort on the question, however it is not clear to me what you mean with 'this gives me all the times for each group'. You get one time for each motecarlo, tracking_id combination right? Also, when working with the random module it can be helpful to set the seed so you and others can reproduce your test set, e.g. `random.seed(1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any relational database all tables are unordered sets, so there is no first or last row.
So this part of your code:

```
.apply(first_time_if_exists)  # Get time of first pass for each group
```

is meaningless in SQL unless there is a column that denotes the order of the rows, something like an auto incremented `id` or a datetime column with the timestamp of the insertion of the row.

SQLite provides for all tables the column [`rowid`](https://www.sqlite.org/rowidtable.html) which you can use for this purpose, but it is not always guaranteed that its max value will be the last inserted row, because after deletions of rows the missing values of `rowid`s may be reused.

If you can use such a column, say `ordercolumn`, then you can do what you want with:

```
SELECT montecarlo, tracking_id, time
FROM mytable
WHERE passed = 1
GROUP BY montecarlo, tracking_id
HAVING MIN(ordercolumn)
```

This query, although it would not be valid in other databases, it is valid in SQLite and returns for each combination of `montecarlo` and `tracking_id` the row where the value of `ordercolumn` is minimum.
You could use instead of `ordercolumn` the column `rowid` (under the restriction I already mentioned), or any other column that sets the order of the rows.

You could also do the same with `FIRST_VALUE()` window function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT montecarlo, tracking_id, 
       FIRST_VALUE(time) OVER (PARTITION BY montecarlo, tracking_id ORDER BY ordercolumn) AS time
FROM mytable
WHERE passed = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer! The `FIRST_VALUE` method is something I had no idea existed. The multiple examples were very helpful

Comment: @natemcintosh you can read about SQLite's window functions support (since version 3.25.0) here: https://sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html